# Use already done computation wisely

Tags: dask, dask-delayed

If I've got a dask dataframe df. Now I apply some computation on it.

> Mathematically,
>
> df1 = f1(df)
>
> df2 = f2(df1)
>
> df3 = f3(df1)

Now if I run, `df2.compute()`, now after that if I run `df1.compute()`. How can I stop dask from recomputing the result of `df1`?

Taking the other case, if I run `df3.compute()`, then `df2.compute()`. How can I tell dask to use the already computed value of `df1` (which is computed in `df3.compute()`) in running `df2.compute()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dask.persist` to create a dask dataframe with the subgraph computed, or computing.

If you are using the local scheduler then you should take a look at dask.cache.Cache

```
from dask.cache import Cache
cache = Cache(4e9).register()
```

Comment: So in above example in 1st case, do I need to do dask.persist(df1) or dask.persist(df2) ?